# BASH: how to put variable inside regex?

Tags: regex, bash, variables, grep

i'm trying to get working the following code:

```
searchfile="availables.txt"
read searchterm
grep_params="-i ^.*${searchterm}.*;.*$' $searchfile"
egrep $grep_params
```

which should echo all lines beginning with the $searchterm and followed by ";". But if the searchterm contains spaces it doesn't work (eg: "black eyed peas"), it gives me the following output:

```
egrep: eyed: No such file or directory
egrep: peas.*;.*$": No such file or directory
egrep: "availables.txt": No such file or directory
```

Comment: <a href="http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050">BASH FAQ entry #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"</a>

Answer (score 3):

Just Bash

```
searchfile="file"
read searchterm
shopt -s nocasematch
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *"$searchterm"*";"* ) echo "$line";;
    esac
done < "$searchfile"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to control word splitting here. That is done through arrays. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

```
searchfile="availables.txt"
read searchterm
grep_params=(-i "^.*${searchterm}.*;.*$" $searchfile)
egrep "${grep_params[@]}"
```

But don't use `egrep` - use `grep -E` instead, as the first is deprecated.
But I would have changed your code like that:

```
searchfile="availables.txt"
read searchterm
grep_params="^.*${searchterm}.*;.*$"
grep -E -i "$grep_params" $searchfile
```

Comment: thanks, also: Is there any way to escape all spaces, brackets, etc.? So i can put in searchterm the string ".*"

Comment: Didn't get you. What forbids you to enter `.*` when being asked for `searchterm`?

Comment: if i enter ".*", it matches all the line

Comment: Remove `.*$` in the grep_params, then it will match up to the ";"

Comment: well, if i enter ".*", it should matches only lines that have "something.*something;something". Instead it matches all lines. I would have something that converts the string ".*" into "\.\*", in other words something that escape all the special character like .,\,/,*,$, etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933474/escape-characters-contained-by-bash-variable-in-regex-pattern

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking for is something like:

```
searchfile="availables.txt"
read searchterm
regex="${searchterm}"'.*;'
egrep "${grep_params}" "${searchfile}"
```

Note that I simplified your regex (I hope I got it right!).

However, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrar noted, this will fail in complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

As this is s regex, try to replace the " " with `\s`. This stands for a whitespace character.

"black\seyed\speas"

Comment: This will also match other whitespace characters, which may not be what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to pass the params through xargs:

```
searchfile="availables.txt"
read searchterm
grep_params="-i '^.*${searchterm}.*;.*$' $searchfile"
echo "$grep_params" | xargs egrep
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here by searching for "bash variable in a regex"

I solved it by changing the regex delimiters from "/" to "+"

Even though it has nothing to do with egrep, I'm adding my solution for other people who arrive from similar searches:

```
SYBASELOG="/opt/sybase/ASE-12_5/install/SYBASE.log"
MAILBODY="Some text and then the replacement placeholder:

   [MSGFILE]

   and some more text"

# Some proecessing...

MAILBODY=`echo "${MAILBODY}" | sed -e "s+\[MSGFILE\]+"${SYBASELOG}"+"`
```

And yes, I see now that it had little to do with bash and everything to do with the slashes in the log file variable.  D'oh!