# Is there an easy way to pass a "raw" string to grep?

Tags: bash, escaping, grep, command-line-interface

`grep` can't be fed "raw" strings when used from the command-line, since some characters need to be escaped to not be treated as literals. For example:

```
$ grep '(hello|bye)' # WON'T MATCH 'hello'
$ grep '\(hello\|bye\)' # GOOD, BUT QUICKLY BECOMES UNREADABLE
```

I was using `printf` to auto-escape strings:

```
$ printf '%q' '(some|group)\n'
\(some\|group\)\\n
```

This produces a bash-escaped version of the string, and using backticks, this can easily be passed to a grep call:

```
$ grep `printf '%q' '(a|b|c)'`
```

However, it's clearly not meant for this: some characters in the output are not escaped, and some are unnecessarily so. For example:

```
$ printf '%q' '(^#)'
\(\^#\)
```

The `^` character should not be escaped when passed to `grep`.

Is there a cli tool that takes a raw string and returns **a bash-escaped version of the string that can be directly used as pattern with grep**? How can I achieve this in pure bash, if not?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to escape and what you don't. If you want to look for literal strings, use grep -F.

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer, please take another look.

Comment: I still don't understand.  How are you getting the strings into the shell to `printf` them in the first place?  By that point they're just as ready to be passed to `printf` as to `grep`.

Comment: I added an example at the beginning

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn - single quoted strings are not interpolated. Single quote your example.

Comment: `grep -F \(some\|group\)\\n` obviously works (that's the whole point of `%q`...)

Comment: Related: [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/367456)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are attempting to get `grep` to use Extended Regular Expression syntax, the way to do that is to use `grep -E` (aka `egrep`).  You should also know about `grep -F` (aka `fgrep`) and, in newer versions of GNU Coreutils, `grep -P`.

Background: The original `grep` had a fairly small set of regex operators; it was Ken Thompson's original regular expression implementation.  A new version with an extended repertoire was developed later, and for compatibility reasons, got a different name.  With GNU `grep`, there is only one binary, which understands the traditional, basic RE syntax if invoked as `grep`, and ERE if invoked as `egrep`.  Some constructs from `egrep` are available in `grep` by using a backslash escape to introduce special meaning.

Subsequently, the Perl programming language has extended the formalism even further; this regex dialect seems to be what most newcomers erroneously expect `grep`, too, to support.  With `grep -P`, it does; but this is not yet widely supported on all platforms.

So, in `grep`, the following characters have a special meaning: `^$[]*.\`

In `egrep`, the following characters also have a special meaning: `()|+?{}`.  (The braces for repetition were not in the original `egrep`.) The grouping parentheses also enable backreferences with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

In many versions of `grep`, you can get the `egrep` behavior by putting a backslash before the `egrep` specials.  There are also special sequences like `\<\>`.

In Perl, a huge number of additional escapes like `\w` `\s` `\d` were introduced.  In Perl 5, the regex facility was substantially extended, with non-greedy matching `*?` `+?` etc, non-grouping parentheses `(?:...)`, lookaheads, lookbehinds, etc.

... Having said that, if you really do want to convert `egrep` regular expressions to `grep` regular expressions *without invoking any external process*, try `${regex/pattern/substitution}` for each of the `egrep` special characters; but recognize that this does not handle character classes, negated character classes, or backslash escapes correctly.

Comment: Nice answer. Regular expressions are a powerful tool, but unfortunately many commands implement them differently.

Comment: [Why are there so many different regular expression dialects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298007/why-are-there-so-many-different-regular-expression-dialects) is related, though the answers there are less detailed.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-any-of-s-s-d-d-w-w-etc which has an answer of mine with workarounds if you are trying to use some PCRE features in Bash (or more generally POSIX regular expressions).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33908887 has some notes around the regular expression support in Python and hence the lineage from Perl and ultimately Henry Spencer's implementation.

Answer (score 73):

If you want to search for an exact string,

```
grep -F '(some|group)\n' ...
```

`-F` tells `grep` to treat the pattern as is, with no interpretation as a regex.

(This is often available as `fgrep` as well.)

Comment: `fgrep` is defined by POSIX, so it should be available, but is technically deprecated.

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer, please take another look.

Comment: @jordanm A bit harsher than deprecated, even.  It's marked LEGACY in POSIX.2, and has not been carried forward to any specification past 1997.

Comment: The OP expects `(hello|bye)` to match "hello".  So I think this is the answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @tripleee That's totally not how I interpreted the question... but I can see that possibility.  Well, let's see if your answer is to the right question :)

Comment: That's totally not what I meant :(

Comment: This doesn't always work. Try e.g: echo "A-B-C" | grep -F "-B-"

Comment: @LLL that's because the pattern `-B-` looks like an option (indeed `-B` is a valid grep option), you need to use the `--` special option to terminate option parsing; i.e. `echo A-B-C | grep -F -- -B-` (note that the quotes you used are unnecessary and do nothing in this case, and they are stripped by the shell before invoking grep)

Answer (score 32):

When I use grep -E with user provided strings I escape them with this

```
ere_quote() {
    sed 's/[][\.|$(){}?+*^]/\\&/g' <<< "$*"
}
```

example run

```
ere_quote ' \ $ [ ] ( ) { } | ^ . ? + *'
# output
# \\ \$ \[ \] \( \) \{ \} \| \^ \. \? \+ \*
```

This way you may safely insert the quoted string in your regular expression.

e.g. if you wanted to find each line starting with the user content, with the user providing funny strings as .*

```
userdata=".*"
grep -E -- "^$(ere_quote "$userdata")" <<< ".*hello"
# if you have colors in grep you'll see only ".*" in red
```

Comment: The character class/set in your ere_quote function is missing the "/" character, as a result it won't escape it.

Comment: @fholzer why should "/" be quoted? It has no special meaning in a regexp. If you are using it as delimiter you can use different delimiters, or escape it, but that is different from being evalutated as part of a regexp

Comment: While technically correct, my assumption was that the output of the `ere_quote` function would subsequently used in e.g. sed. While one could use a different delimiter, whatever delimiter would be chosen would again need to be escaped. So, true, while technically the slash holds no special meaning in regex in general, it might be worth noting that when `ere_quote` output is used later in the script with certain tools, it would make sense to amend the character class with the chosen delimiter of those tools, if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I think that previous answers are not complete because they miss one important thing, namely string which begin with dash (-). So while this **won't** work:

```
echo "A-B-C" | grep -F "-B-"
```

This one will:

```
echo "A-B-C" | grep -F -- "-B-"
```

Comment: `grep` has the `-e` option precisely so you can unambiguously pass in a pattern which starts with a dash. This has nothing to do with regex syntax per se.

Answer (score 2):

```
quote() {
    sed 's/[^\^]/[&]/g;s/[\^]/\\&/g' <<< "$*"
}
```

Usage: `grep [OPTIONS] "$(quote [STRING])"`

This function has some substantial benefits:

- `quote` is **independent from the regex flavor**. You can use `quote`'s output in

  - `grep` (`-G`)` (BRE, the default)
  - `grep -E` (ERE)
  - `grep -P` (PCRE)
  - `sed` (`-E`) `"s/$(quote [STRING])/.../"` (as long as you don't use `\`, `[`, or `]` instead of `/`).
- `quote` even **works in corner cases** that are not directly quoting related, for instance

  - [Leading `-`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640965/6770384) are quoted so that they aren't misinterpreted as options by `grep`.
  - Trailing spaces are quoted so that the aren't removed by `$(...)`.

`quote` only fails if `[STRING]` contains linebreaks. But in general there is no fix for this since tools like `grep` and `sed` may not support linebreaks in their search pattern (even if they are written as `\n`).

Also, there is the drawback that the quoted output usually is three times longer than the unquoted input.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to comment example below which shows that substring "-B" is iterpreted by grep as a command line option and the command failed.

```
echo "A-B-C" | grep -F "-B-"
```

*grep* has a special option for this case:

> **-e PATTERNS, --regexp=PATTERNS**
>                 Use  PATTERNS  as the patterns.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the -f (--file) option,
>                 search for all patterns given.  This option can be used to protect a pattern beginning with “-”.

So a fix for the issue is:

```
echo "A-B-C" | grep -F -e "-B-" -
```

Comment: This seems to basically repeat LLL's answer from 2017, albeit with a slightly different solution.