# Does the Python regular expression module use BRE or ERE?

Tags: python, regex, posix

It appears that POSIX splits regular expression implementations into two kinds: Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) and Extended Regular Expressions (ERE).

Python [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) reference does not seem to specify.

Comment: it's ERE. + PCRE .......

Comment: TLDR of the answers: Between BRE and ERE, it's closer to ERE, but closer still to PCRE, which is not specified by POSIX and supports more features.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Except for some similarity in the syntax, `re` module **doesn't follow POSIX standard for regular expressions**.

### Different matching semantics

POSIX regular expression (which can be implemented with a DFA/NFA or even a backtracking engine) always finds the **leftmost longest match**, while `re` module is a backtracking engine which finds the **leftmost "earliest" match** ("earliest" according to the search order defined by the regular expression).

The difference in the matching semantics can be observed in the case of matching `(Prefix|PrefixSuffix)` against `PrefixSuffix`.

- In POSIX-complaint implementation of POSIX regex (not those which only borrows the syntax), the regex will match `PrefixSuffix`.
- In contrast, `re` engine (and many other backtracking regex engines) will match `Prefix` only, since `Prefix` is specified first in the alternation.

The difference can also be seen in the case of matching `(xxx|xxxxx)*` against `xxxxxxxxxx` (a string of 10 `x`'s):

- On Cygwin:

  ```
  $ [[ "xxxxxxxxxx" =~ (xxx|xxxxx)* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  xxxxxxxxxx
  ```

  All 10 `x`'s are matched.
- In Python:

  ```
  >>> re.search(r'(?:xxx|xxxxx)*', 'xxxxxxxxxxx').group(0)
  'xxxxxxxxx'
  ```

  Only 9 `x`'s are matched, since it picks the first item in alternation `xxx` in all 3 repetitions, and nothing forces it to backtrack and try the second item in alternation)

### POSIX-exclusive regular expression features

Apart from the difference in matching semantics, POSIX regular expression also define syntax for **collating symbols**, **equivalence class expressions**, and **collation-based character range**. These features greatly increase the expressive power of the regex.

Taking equivalence class expression as example, from the documentation:

> An equivalence class expression shall represent the set of collating elements belonging to an equivalence class, as described in Collation Order. [...]. The class shall be expressed by enclosing any one of the collating elements in the equivalence class within bracket-equal ( `"[="` and `"=]"` ) delimiters. **For example, if `'a'`, `'à'`, and `'â'` belong to the same equivalence class, then `"[[=a=]b]"`, `"[[=à=]b]"`, and `"[[=â=]b]"` are each equivalent to `"[aàâb]"`**. [...]

Since these features heavily depend on the locale settings, the same regex may behave differently on different locale. It also depends on the locale data on the system for the collation order.

### `re` regular expression features

`re` borrows the syntax from Perl, but not all features in Perl regex are implemented in `re`. Below are some regex features available in `re` which is unavailable in POSIX regular expression:

- Greedy/lazy quantifier, which specifies the order to expand a quantifier.

  <sup>While people usually call the `*` in POSIX greedy, it actually only specifies the lower bound and upper bound of the repetition in POSIX. The so-called "greedy" behavior is due to the leftmost longest match rule.</sup>
- Look-around assertion (look-ahead and look-behind)
- Conditional pattern `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`
- Short-hand constructs: `\b`, `\s`, `\d`, `\w` (some POSIX regular expression engine may implement these, since the standard leaves the behavior undefined for these cases)

Comment: This answer completely fails to describe the Perl-originated features in the PCRE dialect used in Python.  There is a large number of extensions which are a substantial superset of anything defined in POSIX (shorthands like `\d`, `\s`, `\w`; greedy and nonbacktracking quantifiers; lookaheads and lookbehinds; etc etc).

Comment: @tripleee: I only intend to highlight the differences between re and POSIX, and stress that they are different engines. Of course, there are other differences between them. I probably will update this post later to highlight some features that Python re has but POSIX doesn't.

Comment: There's at least one more difference. In POSIX REs, the backslash \ loses its properties when inside a bracket expression. Not so in Python. From time to time you see grep REs that match backslashes when they shouldn't for this reason. For example, in Python, `re.search(r'[\[]', '\\')` returns no results, but in the shell `echo '\' | grep '[\[]'` returns a backslash as a result.

Answer (score 11):

Neither.  It's basically the PCRE dialect, but a distinct implementation.

The very first sentence in the `re` documentation says:

> This module provides regular expression matching operations similar to those found in Perl.

While this does not immediately reveal to a newcomer how they are related to e.g. POSIX regular expressions, it should be common knowledge that Perl 4 and later Perl 5 provided a substantially expanded feature set over the regex features of earlier tools, including what POSIX mandated for `grep -E` aka ERE.

The [`perlre` manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) describes the regular expression features in more detail, though you'll find much the same details in a different form in the Python documentation.  The Perl manual page contains this bit of history:

> The patterns used in Perl pattern matching evolved from those supplied in the Version 8 regex routines. (The routines are derived (distantly) from Henry Spencer's freely redistributable reimplementation of the V8 routines.)

(Here, V8 refers to [Version 8 Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_8_Unix).  Spencer's library basically [(re)implemented POSIX regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Spencer#Free_Software_contributions).)

Perl 4 had a large number of convenience constructs like `\d`, `\s`, `\w` as well as symbolic shorthands like `\t`, `\f`, `\n`.  Perl 5 added a significant set of extensions (which is still growing slowly) including, but not limited to,

- Non-greedy quantifiers
- Non-backtracking quantifiers
- Unicode symbol and property support
- Non-grouping parentheses
- Lookaheads and lookbehinds
- ... Basically anything that starts with `(?`

As a result, the "regular" expressions are by no means strictly "regular" any longer.

This was reimplemented in a portable library by Philip Hazel, originally for the Exim mail server; his [PCRE library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) has found its way into myriad different applications, including a number of programming languages (Ruby, PHP, Python, etc).  Incidentally, in spite of the name, the library is not strictly "Perl compatible" (any longer); there are differences in features as well as in behavior.  (For example, Perl internally changes `*` to something like `{0,32767}` while PCRE does something else.)

An earlier version of Python actually had a different regex implementation, and there are [plans to change it again](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (though it will remain basically PCRE).  This is the situation as of Python 2.7 / 3.5.