# Invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence, Postgres, Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to escape a string `яблуко*` for Postgres regex query:

```
name = re.escape('яблуко*')
Model.objects.filter(name__iregex='^%s' % name)
```

This gives me:

> Invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I know that I can do it with `istartswith`, just wondering why regex is not working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Why are you using `re.escape` at all? Shouldn't it just be `Model.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'яблуко*')` [per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iregex)? Also, what does `name` look like if you print it before the queryset filter?

Comment: why not `name = r'яблуко*'`? it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `re.escape` does escape way too much for PostgreSQL - it does escape all non ASCII chars, while PostgreSQL doesn't support escape sequences for unknown chars - in this case it's all the unicode chars:

```
>>> print re.escape('яблуко*')
\я\б\л\у\к\о\*
```

In the end it's not really possible to mix Python regexp engine (for escaping) with database regexp engine (for evaluation). Unfortunately Django doesn't provide way to do this. In [Weblate](https://weblate.org), I've solved this by writing custom function to escape the regexp, see https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/commit/7425a749b44abafe36d8f1c9db018f57684e5983

Comment: The issue is more that the Python regular expression dialect is a variant of PCRE (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33908887/253599) and that PostgreSQL uses POSIX regular expressions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).  The function referenced here escapes the POSIX regular expression special characters, and also the NUL character (though it's unclear if this is required).