# Grep with regualr expression not matching the whole string

Tags: regex, grep

This might be a dumb question, but ChatGPT does not do the job.

In my understanding, `[a-zA-Z\s]+` should greedily match a string with letters or spaces, as I tested with https://regexr.com/ and Python.

```py
import re
input_string = "abcd efgh--hello world adf sd"
pattern = r"[a-zA-Z\s]+"
match = re.search(pattern, input_string)
print(match.group())
print('---')
matches = re.findall(pattern, input_string)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
> 
abcd efgh
---
abcd efgh
hello world adf sd
```

However, I do not know why `grep -Eo` is not giving the same result.

```
▶ echo ""abcd efgh--hello world adf sd"" | grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z\s]+"
abcd
efgh
hello
world
adf
sd
```

My goal is to get the same result as the Python script using `grep`. My guess is that `grep` with `-o` is not doing a greedy search, but I am not sure about that and I do not know the solution to fix it.

Comment: `-E` select POSIX [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) style regex. `\s` has no special meaning inside `[`...`]` and just means "s" outside it. If your grep has `-P` that select PCRE style regex.

Comment: but even that will have different behaviour in some cases. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33907156/10971581

Comment: @jhnc Thanks a lot! My grep does not have `-P`, but replacing `\s` with a literal space does the job.

Comment: Start using POSIX character classes instead of hard-coding characters to avoid getting bitten by locale changes, missing chars, non-portable constructs, etc. e.g. `[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+`.