# How to scrub emails from all CSVs in a directory?

Tags: regex, macos, sed, grep

I have this regex that works fine enough for my purposes for identifying emails in CSVs within a directory using `grep` on Mac OS X:

```
grep --no-filename -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b" *
```

I've tried to get this working with sed so that I can replace the emails with `foo@bar.baz`:

```
sed -E -i '' -- 's/\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b/foo@bar.baz/g' *
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work. Admittedly, `sed` and regex are not my strong points. Any ideas?

Comment: Please note that your regex fails on `myAddress+extension@gmail.com`. It leaves the `myAddress`.

Comment: Yep, that's true. I know creating an email for regex is notoriously difficult. But this is good enough for my purposes. I'm not concerned as much with the regex as I am with how to integrate it into sed.

Comment: Do you want to change all files in a directory?

Comment: Is there directory within directory?

Comment: @rock321987 Yes, I want to change all files. There is just 1 directory - it does not need to be recursive.

Comment: `sed -E -i 's/\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b/foo@bar.baz/g' *`..see if it works..its working for me

Comment: @rock321987 I get `sed: 1: "filename.csv": unterminated substitute in regular expression`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108068/discussion-between-foobar0100-and-rock321987).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sed` in `OSX` is broken. Replace it with `GNU sed` using `Homebrew` that will be used as a replacement for the one bundled in OSX. Use this command for installation

```
sudo brew install gnu-sed
```

and use this for `substitution`

```
sed -E -i 's/\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b/foo@bar.baz/g' *
```

[**Reference**](http://marvinsmutterings.calepin.co/fix-broken-sed-on-osx.html)

Comment: "Broken" how? The example you link to shows somebody using incorrect syntax and then concluding that his sed is "broken".

Comment: @BenjaminW. I googled for `unterminated substitute in regular expression` and found that link..The same `sed` is working fine on `ubuntu`

Comment: It's not because it's "broken", it's because they use different dialects of the `sed` scripting language. *BSD (and thus OSX) is closer to the original and to POSIX, whereas GNU `sed` has a large number of nonstandard extensions. Not supporting those extensions is not "broken"; if anything, a script which requires those extensions is.

Comment: @tripleee feel free to edit my answer. I don't know anything about `OSX sed`.. I thought it as standard error

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that `grep` and `sed` support the same regex dialect, but that is not necessarily, or even usually, the case.

If you want a portable solution, you could easily use Perl for this, which however supports yet another regex dialect...

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b/foo@bar.baz/g' *
```

For a bit of an overview of regex dialects, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857890/874188

Your regex kind of sucks, but I understand that is sort of beside the point here.