# Giving error while using grep with array having spaces

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, grep, command-line-arguments

I am trying to `grep` with all elements of array but it is breaking because of spaces.

Below is the value of my array:

```
server:/home/a-hkat # echo "${hitesharray2[@]}"    
ida0481.abc.xyz.net:/J 'ida0481.abc.xyz.net [/J]'

server:/home/a-hkat # declare -p hitesharray2
declare -a hitesharray2='([0]="ida0481.abt.xyz.net:/J" [1]="'\''ida0481.abc.xyz.net [/J]'\''")'
```

Below is the error:

```
server:/home/a-hkat # omnidb -winfs | grep "${hitesharray2[@]}"    
grep: 'ida0481.abc.xyz.net [/J]': No such file or directory
```

Desired result should be as below but using array:

```
server:/home/a-hkataria # omnidb -winfs | grep ida0481.abc.xyz.net:/J    
ida0481.abc.xyz.net:/J 'ida0481.abc.xyz.net [/J]'
```

In short, I want to grep the below lines using an array or some other alternative.

```
server:/home/a-hkat # echo "${hitesharray2[@]}"
amerfs0039.abc.xyz.net:/F 'amerfs0039.abc.xyz.net [/F]'

server:/home/a-hkat # omnidb -winfs | grep amerfs0039.abc.xyz.net:/F
amerfs0039.abc.xyz.net:/F 'amerfs0039.abc.xyz.net [/F]' WinFS
```

Comment: Hi i have updated the question and also include the output of declare -p

Comment: Please clarify, since the question is changing constantly: Do you want to grep with each array value separately? (i.e. `array = (aaa bbb)` and want to `omnidb -winfs | grep aaa` and `omnidb -winfs | grep bbb` ) Or do you want to grep with a string composed with all array values put together? (i.e. `omnidb -winfs | grep "aaa bbb"`)

Answer (score 1):

#### OP's solution

The OP posted in a comment, and I memorialize here for posterity:

> I have solved this problem by using fgrep and then removing all the spaces from output of command omnidb -winfs and array so that it can match perfectly.

`fgrep`, or `grep -F`, treats things like `[]` as literals, where they would normally be considered to be grep metacharacters.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856117/2877364) for more.  Since the OP's text included brackets, using `fgrep` permitted matching that text literally.

#### Original Answer

Your `${hitesharray2[@]}` expands to two words, one for each element of the array.  What you are getting is the same as if you had said

```
omnidb -winfs | grep "${hitesharray2[0]}" "${hitesharray2[1]}"
```

When [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) is given more than one argument, it treats the arguments after the first as filenames.  Here, the second element (with `[/J]`) is treated as a filename.

**Edit** Per your comment, it appears you want to jam all the elements of your array together as a single space-separated word.  You can use:

```
omnidb -winfs | grep "${hitesharray2[*]}"
#        note the asterisk subscript ^
```

Or, if the amount of whitespace varies, you might need to do it the long way:

```
omnidb -winfs | grep "${hitesharray2[0]}\s*${hitesharray2[1]}"
```

See the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#referencing) for more about ways of indexing arrays.

Comment: I want to filer using ida0481.bt.bombardier.net:/J 'ida0481.bt.bombardier.net [/J]'

Comment: @HiteshKataria Did you try `"${hitesharray2[*]}"`?  It looks like that will do what you want, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes i tried but did not work. I have added more details of mu requirement in my question. Please check if you can help me.

Comment: @HiteshKataria Try `grep -F` with any of the options above per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11856117/2877364).  That will prevent `grep` from interpreting the square brackets in your text as part of a pattern.

Comment: Hi Thanks for input. I have solved this problem by using fgrep and then removing all the spaces from output of command omnidb -winfs and array so that it can match perfectly. Thanks again.