# Perl search and replace

Tags: linux, bash, perl, search, replace

I am trying to search for some strings in a file and replace them using perl:

```
perl -pe "s/filename/$FNAME/" Header.xml > $HDIR/$FNAME.xml
```

How can I search and replace multiple string, since adding another commands just overwrites the output file:

```
perl -pe "s/RBRef/$REF/" HeaderRBRS.xml > $HDIR/$FNAME.xml
perl -pe "s/MessageIdentifier/$MessageIdentifier/" HeaderRBRS.xml > $HDIR/$FNAME.xml
perl -pe "s/FileDigestValue/$digestNr/" HeaderRBRS.xml > $HDIR/$FNAME.xml
perl -pe "s/filename/$FNAME/" HeaderRBRS.xml > $HDIR/$FNAME.xml
```

In the last case only `perl -pe "s/filename/$FNAME/" HeaderRBRS.xml > $HDIR/$FNAME.xml` will be executed every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should write a perl script and pass in an array of strings to search and replace.

Comment: You should use a proper library to handle XML files.

Comment: Also, by using double quotes, you're building the Perl code from the shell variable. If the variable contains a slash, the code will break. Using Perl variables would work better, as they're real variables, not just expanding macros.

Comment: What library? @choroba

Comment: I'm a fan of [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), but [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig) isn't bad either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass all substitutions as one argument after `-e`. Delimit them by a semicolon `;`.

```
perl -pe "s/filename/$FNAME/;s/RBRef/$REF/;..." infile > outfile
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Do you know how to escape $ sign if the variable $FNAME contains this character in it?

Comment: @MihaiDumitru Yes, in `bash` write `${FNAME//$/\\$}` instead of `$FNAME`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951928/6770384 for a more general quoting mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver!