# How to change string with sed in Bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have file with parameters:

```
key1: 'testValue'
```

And I want to change the value of the `key1` (`testValue`) according to parameter.

This one is working with hard-coded value:

```
sed -i "s/\(key1:\).*/\1 'newValue'/"  ./myFile
```

I tried with dynamic value:

```
MY_NEW_VALUE= testNewValue
sed -i "s/\(key1:\).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/" ./myFile
```

And I got am error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: [I don't get the error](http://tpcg.io/JPxxLH)

Comment: this one didn't work for me sed -i "s/\(key1:\).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/" ./myFile

Comment: `"s/(key1:).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/"` The `(` and `)` need to be escaped.

Comment: @Kamil - I did escape  "s/\(key1:\).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/

Comment: `MY_NEW_VALUE= testNewValue` → `MY_NEW_VALUE=testNewValue`

Comment: @Biffen -it was in mistake but I still got the error

Comment: It *looks like* you run it with some value of `$MY_NEW_VALUE` that contains a slash. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: It run on docker so I guess it is mac

Comment: As already pointed out by Biffen: It seems like your variable contains special characters for `sed` like `/`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951928/6770384) shows how to quote strings for `grep`. Just add `/` as a special character to be quoted and you should be fine.

Comment: Esacpe `(` like `\(` like in `"s/\(key1:\).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/"`. The `"s/(key1:).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/"` is invalid.

Comment: @Robc - I tried this one and it didn't work sed -i -e "s/\(key1r:\).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/" ./myFile

Comment: @KamilCuk How is that different from what OP is doing?!

Comment: @Robc - sed -i -e "s/\(key1:\).*/\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}/" ./file

Comment: This is the error sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working here:

```
root@foo:~# cat /tmp/c
key1: 'testValue'

root@foo:~# MY_NEW_VALUE="testNewValue"; cat /tmp/c | sed -s "s/\(key1:\).*/\1 '${MY_NEW_VALUE}'/"
key1: 'testNewValue'
```

Edit: Change your line:

```
MY_NEW_VALUE= testNewValue
```

to

```
MY_NEW_VALUE="testNewValue"
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me the same error

Comment: Can you post the result from "env", please.

Comment: It run on docker and I call to script

Comment: Or try replace the slashes with #:
    <pre>sed -i "s#\(key1:\).*#\1 ${MY_NEW_VALUE}#" ./myFile</pre>

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: You are into the docker container ? Or call the command with exec -it ?
Please post your docker command.