# How to copy files with same contents in a different directory

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, diff

I have a directory with many files with different names and some of them are having same contents.

The directory tree is like:

```
dir1/case-1.sc001
dir1/case-1.sc002
.................
dir1/case-1.sc010
dir1/case-1.sc011
..................
.............
dir1/case-1.sc998
dir1/case-1.sc999
```

The file may be more than 999 or less than it.

I want to keep the first files in the main directory and other files with same contents in a new directory.
Is there any workaround for this?
I  tried for `diff, cksum, fslint, rdfind, and fdupes`, detailes about how I executed are give below, as shown below, but all are not working in the same directory with different file names.

```
diff *
fslint .
rdfind .
fdupes -r
cksum case-1*
```

Comment: Show the directory tree, the input and expected output and the code that you have tried that is **not working**

Comment: Dear @Jetchisel  , I have updated the post as per your direction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584817/how-do-i-find-duplicate-files-by-comparing-them-by-size-ie-not-hashing-in-bas  is one link.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/386199/how-to-remove-duplicated-files-in-a-directory This link is using `rm` just change it to `mv` and point it to the destination directory.

Comment: Both are not working for me. In the second link, my bash is not supporting `declare -A arr ` while the version if my bash is 4.4.20.

Comment: While from the first link,  I used 1st accepted answer and getting error "yntax error: "(" unexpected" . I could not figure out the solution. Using second solution from the same answer creates a potential_dups directory and copy all files from the main directory to the potential_dups directory.