# check the content of the files if they are same

Tags: bash, for-loop, diff

i have many .txt files(namely 1.txt, 2.txt 3.txt ...etc) saved in a directory and I want to check if the content of the files inside the directory are same or not

All files should be compared with other file if the content is same then print yes, if content not same print no

For Example:
1.txt

```
a
b
c
```

2.txt

```
a
b
c
```

3.txt

```
1
2
3


expected output when compare two file 1.txt 2.txt

1.txt 2.txt yes

expected output when compare two file 1.txt 3.txt
1.txt 3.txt no

expected output when compare two file 2.txt 3.txt
    2.txt 3.txt no
```

I tried the script

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/nir/dat/*.txt
do
echo $file
diff $file $file+1
done
```

But here problem is it doesnot give the output.Please suggest a better solution thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of questions like this, just search this forum, A utility that does that is `fdupes` for example.

Comment: What is `$file+1` supposed to mean?

Comment: first check what you get with `$file+1`. I get filename like `data.txt+1`

Comment: Instead of comparing all the files, I suggest creating a list of MD5 checksums. Then test if there are any duplicates.

Comment: `md5sum *.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u | uniq -d`

Comment: That means there are no duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find duplicate files by comparing them by size (ie: not hashing) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584817/how-do-i-find-duplicate-files-by-comparing-them-by-size-ie-not-hashing-in-bas)

Comment: What is the expected output? Lets say you have files `a`, `b` and `c` and `a` and `b` have the same contents but `b` and `c` differ. Please edit the expected output to your question, do not post it as a comment.

Comment: So basically compare every file with every other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in bash:

```
for i in *
do 
  for j in *
  do 
    if [[ "$i" < "$j" ]]
    then 
      if cmp -s "$i" "$j"
      then 
        echo $i $j equal
      else 
        echo $i $j differ
      fi
    fi
  done
done
```

Output:

```
1.txt 2.txt equal
1.txt 3.txt differ
2.txt 3.txt differ
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea using an array of the filenames, and borrowing jamesbrown's `cmp` solution:

```
# load list of files into array flist[]

flist=(*)

# iterate through all combinations; '${#flist[@]}' ==> number of elements in array

for ((i=0; i<${#flist[@]}; i++))
do
    for ((j=i+1; j<${#flist[@]}; j++))
    do
         # default status = "no" (ie, are files the same?)

         status=no

         # if files are different this generates a return code of 1 (aka true),
         # so the follow-on assignment (status=yes) is executed

         cmp -s "${flist[${i}]}" "${flist[${j}]}" && status=yes

         echo "${flist[${i}]} ${flist[${j}]} ${status}"
    done
done
```

For the 3 files listed in the question this generates:

```
1.txt 2.txt yes
1.txt 3.txt no
2.txt 3.txt no
```