# summarise NA data from datafile on command line in linux / bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a data file with missing values

I want to summarise this data and find out how many NA there are in the whole data file and in certain specific cols

I have tried

```
grep -i "NA" datafile.gz | wc -l
```

and

```
awk 'NA' datafile.gz | wc -l
```

But they both print '1' which is not right

Any ideas?

### EDIT

@Roadowl provided

```
zgrep -i "na" datafile.gz
```

Which gives the total number of NA, how do I specify by column?

```
grep -i "na" datafile.gz | awk '$3=="na"'
```

Does not work

Comment: As triage, try zgrep instead of grep.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: To help you debug this problem, run the `grep` commands _without_ piping into `wc`. Then you'll see why Roadowl's suggestion is on-point.

Comment: Appreciate your advice! @roadowl suggestion gives me the total NA - thanks - do you know why "" zgrep -i "na" datafile.gz | awk '$3=="na"' "" does not give it me for the column 3?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. Basic questions about command-line literacy might be better suited for our sibling sites  [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] (where the latter is significantly more geared towards newcomers, but also specific in scope to just a single Linux distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here seems to be that you haven't noticed the difference between compressed data and plain text. Most Unix tools only work on the latter.

But first: Your attempts will look for "na" as a substring of any value in any column. So "banana" will match because ... well, I imagine you can see why.

Without seeing your actual data, it's hard to know what exactly you need, but for looking for entries which are exactly "NA" case-insensitively in column 3 of a tab-delimited file, try

```
awk -F '\t' 'tolower($3) == "na"' file
```

The `tolower()` call converts to lower case so that you can then compare to a single string; this will cover all case variations of `"NA"`, `"Na"`, `"nA"`, or `"na"` but only look for an exact match after case conversion, instead of looking for a substring. (This assumes you don't have e.g. whitespace around the values in the column, too; it really is an exact comparison.)

To get the count, pipe to `wc -l` (or refactor the Awk script:

```
awk -F '\t' 'tolower($3) == "na" { sum += 1 } END { print sum }' file
```

Probably read a 15-minute introduction to Awk if this isn't obvious.)

Perhaps more usefully, include file name and line number

```
awk -F '\t' 'tolower($3) == "na" { print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0 }' file
```

(You can pass multiple file names, and then the `FILENAME` makes more sense.)

To examine a different column, replace `$3` with e.g. `$42` to examine column 42. To use a different delimiter, put the delimiter instead of `'\t'` after `-F`.  This still doesn't correctly deal with e.g. quoting in CSV files (maybe switch to a language which knows how to parse CSV in all its variations correctly, like Python, or use a dedicated CSV tool -- I hear there's one called  `csvtool`).

If your file is compressed, you can't `grep` (or Awk or `sed` or etc) the compressed data directly; you have to uncompress it first:

```
gzcat datafile.gz |
awk -F '\t' -v gzfile="datafile.gz" 'tolower($3) == "na" { print gzfile ":" FNR ":" $0 }'
```

Notice how you don't put a file name after the Awk script when the input comes from a pipe (or not just Awk actually; any tool which is capable of reading a file or standard input, as is the norm among Unix text-processing tools).

The above also shows how to pass a string into Awk as a variable (`-v variable="value"`).  This might be more useful if you have multiple files you want to loop over:

```
for datafile in datafile.gz datafile0.gz datafile1.gz; do
    gzcat "$datafile" |
    awk -F '\t' -v gzfile="$datafile" 'tolower($3) == "na" { print gzfile ":" FNR ":" $0 }'
done
```

Slightly bewilderingly, the `$datafile` variable is a *shell* variable (Bash or Zsh or what have you) which is entirely distinct from Awk's internal variables. We use the `-v` trick from above to make it available to Awk in the variable `gzfile`.

You *could* use `grep` (which reads plain text) or `gzgrep` (which can read `gzip`-compressed data directly) as well, but then you want to pass in a regular expression which targets the specific column. Just to show how it's done, here is a regex which says "something with no tabs, followed by a tab, followed by something with no tabs, followed by a tab, followed by `na`, followed by a tab" which (once you wrap your head around it) targets the third column.

```
gzgrep -Ei -c $'^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\tna\t' filename.gz
```

The `$'...'` notation is Bash-specific and allows us to use the symbol `\t` instead of a literal tab in the regular expression.  The `-c` option to `grep` asks it to report how many matching lines it found, so you don't even need `wc -l` here.  The `-E` option selects a slightly less arcane and more modern regular expression dialect than the default from the early 1970s. (It's still not properly modern by any standard; the "extended" dialect is from the *mid*-1970s, with some later brushing up by the POSIX standardization in the 1990s. Newer tools support a plethora of extensions which are [not standard in `grep`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856054/is-there-an-easy-way-to-pass-a-raw-string-to-grep/11857890#11857890))

To look for `na` alone with tabs on both sides in any column, try

```
gzgrep -Eic -e $'^na\t|\tna\t|\tna$' filename.gz
```

where `|` in the regular expression stands for "or", and `^na\t` is the regular expression for `na` bracketed by beginning of line on one side and a tab on the other, and `\tna$` is the same for end of line.

If you don't use Bash, you can remove the `$` before `'` and type a literal tab, usually with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>

Files whose name ends with `.gz` are compressed with `gzip`; there are other compression tools which conventionally use file extensions like `.Z` (plain old `compress`, from the dark ages), `.bz2` (`bzip2`), `.xz` (`xz`) etc; most of these ship with a `bzcat` or similar tool which performs the same job as `gzcat` for `gzip` files, and some will also have something like `bzgrep` to parallel `gzgrep`. (To add to the alphabet soup, `gzcat` could also mean GNU `zcat` on some systems! Then it handles `.Z` files, not `.gz` files).

Unix-based systems generally don't rely on the file extension to identify the type of a file, but the human convention is to add an extension when you compress something, and many of the tools will do that automatically (so for example `gzip file` creates `file.gz`).

A quick examination of a compressed file, perhaps with a hex dump tool, should reveal why `grep` doesn't work directly on the file. The compressed data is a tightly packed oblique binary which simply does not contain the uncompressed data in any easily discoverable form (unless you learn a lot about compression!)